# implement a special font and looking its name

Tags: fonts

I wish to write our manuscript by the font of this document:

[image]

We think it is legible and beautiful. However, we do not know what is the type of font (the name of that) to be implemented on our manuscript.

Does anyone have an experience for this font? Is anyone familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is a variant/clone of Charter.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Although the electronic and magnetic transitions in the orthorhombic rare-earth
nickelates show relatively large responses in the resistivity and susceptibility
measurements, identifying the order parameters and the microscopic mechanism
behind these transitions has remained challenging. The metal-insulator and
paramagnetic-antiferromagnetic transitions in these materials
\[
a+b=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also use the not so different Utopia, or clone thereof, for instance loading `fourier` that perhaps has better covering for math.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

Although the electronic and magnetic transitions in the orthorhombic rare-earth
nickelates show relatively large responses in the resistivity and susceptibility
measurements, identifying the order parameters and the microscopic mechanism
behind these transitions has remained challenging. The metal-insulator and
paramagnetic-antiferromagnetic transitions in these materials
\[
a+b=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use Erewhon:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{erewhon}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}

\begin{document}

Although the electronic and magnetic transitions in the orthorhombic rare-earth
nickelates show relatively large responses in the resistivity and susceptibility
measurements, identifying the order parameters and the microscopic mechanism
behind these transitions has remained challenging. The metal-insulator and
paramagnetic-antiferromagnetic transitions in these materials
\[
a+b=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woderful.....and Fantastic Thank you Very much

Comment: It does look really close, and if OP is happy that's great. But the font OP posted doesn't quite look like Fourier-GUT. Compare for example the serif on the arm of the lower-case k (it's facing both ways, while in Fourier it only faces forwards). It's probably Charter, but hard to tell from that quality (and it's more hassle-free anyway).

Comment: @TivV You are perfectly right.